# Control + W shortcut not working in Finder and Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, finder, shortcut

I set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> as a shortcut for all applications in the System Preferences => Keyboard => Shortcuts.

They are working in many apps (like Safari), but not in Terminal and in Finder.

Is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> a system shortcut?

I shouldn't have conflicts with other shortcuts with the same combination of keys, the yellow warning triangle is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> is an assigned shortcut in `Bash`. Notice, I said, `Bash` and not "Terminal" - basically it's present across all systems from Linux, BSD, macOS and Unix.

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> is "delete word."  It's similar to the  <kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd> (aka Backspace) except it deletes an entire word.

For more info on keyboard shortcuts see:  https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html

Comment: Thank you. Do you think is it possible to override the Bash shortcuts? If it is, do you think it would be a bad practise?

Comment: I wouldn't.  Remember the shell is just a "window" or "portal" to send commands to the OS.  It's expecting certain control or escape sequences to perform different functions (i.e. Ctrl-G is the bell).  Reassigning it might have undesired consequences.